# Como definir um evento para ser executado quando o aplicativo for terminar em PyQt5?

Tags: python-3.x, eventos, pyqt-5

Eu estou criando uma aplicação em PyQt5 e preciso executar um código quando o aplicativo estiver finalizando. Para isso, eu pensei em sobrescrever o método `quit` da classe `QApplication`:

```
class MyApp(QApplication):
    def quit(self):
        print("Meu código...")
        super().quit()
```

O problema é que esse método não está sendo executado quando o programa termina. Minha dúvida é: como eu posso definir um evento "`on_quit`" para a `QApplication` em PyQt5?

Answer (score 0):

existe o evento `closeEvent` que pode ajudar nesse caso, ele é chamado quando o usuario fecha a janela, veja o exemplo:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys


class Test(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(100,100,600,600)


    def closeEvent(self,e):
        # sua logica antes do programa fechar 
        print("print executando antes de fechar a aplicacao")
        #fim do codigo a ser executado antes do programa fecha
        e.accept()
        



app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = Test()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Sim, eu conheço esse evento mas não é o que eu procuro. Preciso criar mesmo um "on_quit" para o **application**, sem depender de widgets.